# Is 甲州街道沿い a relative attribute to 今の八王子市

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0202.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-closeup_002

The sentence in question:
文化１４年、西暦１８１７年の１２月２９日の午後２時ごろ、甲州街道沿いにある宿場町だった今の八王子市とその周辺の日野市や多摩市に、雷のようなごう音とともに隕石の雨が降り注ぎました。

My attempt at translation:
"(??文化１４年??) around 29.12.1817, 2.p.m, in nowadays Hachioji City, which existed along Koshu Kaido and was an inntown, and in the surrounding Hinoshi and Tamashi, a thunderous roar like lightning thunder together with a rain of meteorites rained down incessantly."

I think 甲州街道沿いにある宿場町だった今の八王子市 and その周辺の日野市や多摩市 are both local adverbials, connected through と and made local by に. 
However, especially 甲州街道沿いにある宿場町だった今の八王子市 seems rather complex and Im not sure wether I resolved the attributes correctly.

Comment: You misspell 'whether' on nearly every post. A 'wether' is a castrated ram. Consider this a kind warning from the spelling police.

Comment: Ouh, yeah Ill try not to forget :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On December 29th in year 14 of the Bunka period (1817), at approximately 2:00 PM,  a sound akin to thunder accompanied by a hail of meteorite fell upon the town of Yadoba-cho (which was located) alongside the Koshu-kaido, (which is) modern-day Hachioji City and the surrounding cities of Hino and Tama.

> [文化１４年](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/guide/koyomi.html)、(西暦１８１７年)の１２月２９日の午後２時ごろ、[December 29, 2:00 pm]
>
> 甲州街道沿いにある宿場町だった [In what was Yadobacho, alongside the Koshu-kaido]
>
> 今の八王子市とその周辺の日野市や多摩市に、[Modern Hachioji and its surrounding cities]
>
> 雷のようなごう音とともに隕石の雨が降り注ぎました。 [Thunder along with rain of meteorites]

_____だった、今の＿＿＿＿ is fairly common sentence structure when describing a region which has changed names and/or boundaries.  So, in that sense 宿場町 and 八王子 are related.